# Identify 90'degree projection between two points

Tags: python, math, vector, projection

In `python` I have two points, A and B in 2D.

I have a user who is traveling between these 2 points (now a vector?).

These points are arbitrarily far apart.

I want to calculate 2 projections(?) at half way between these 2 points 100m away from the original line, one projection at 90 degrees and the other at 180 degrees.

[image]

In the above image, I have points A and B, while I want to calculate points C and D.

Can somebody help me with this math calculation?

Comment: Sorry, but SO is not a analytic geometry side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the direction vector from A to B:

```
ab = (x2 - x, y2 - y)
```

Then, the vector that is orthogonal to this line is:

```
orth = (y - y2, x2 - x)
```

The length of this vector (and of the direction vector) is:

```
l = sqrt((x2-x)^2 + (y2-y)^2)
```

The midpoint on the line is

```
m = 1/2 * (x + x2, y + y2)
```

Finally, the two points C and D are:

```
C/D = m +- orth * 100 / l
```

Answer (score 0):

following Nico's Answer, this is how it can look like.

```py
import math
def orthogonal_point(ax, ay, bx, by, amp):
    dir_x = bx - ax
    dir_y = by - ay
    ortho_x = ay - by
    ortho_y = bx - ax
    mid_x = (ax + bx) * 0.5
    mid_y = (ay + by) * 0.5
    len = math.sqrt(dir_x**2 + dir_y**2)
    factor = amp / len
    return mid_x + (ortho_x * factor), mid_y + (dir_x * factor)
```

or shortened

```
def orthogonal_point(ax, ay, bx, by, amp):
    dir_x = bx - ax
    dir_y = by - ay
    amplify = amp / math.sqrt(dir_x**2 + dir_y**2)
    mid_x = (ax + bx) * 0.5
    mid_y = (ay + by) * 0.5
    return mid_x + ((ay - by) * amplify), mid_y + (dir_x * amplify)
```

positive or negative amplification `amp` declares if you get point above or below the vector defined by `ax,ay` to `bx,by`